# Disappearing Cursor pointer in input text field of ionic ios app

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic application.I have a problem with keyboard in iphone 4s with iOS 9, when I click on any text field the keyboard pops up but, I can't see cursor and  what I am typing in the input textbox, it shows nothing when I type, but when I change my focus to another field, the text automatically appears. Anyone has got the same issue? What did you do to rectify it?

[image]

Comment: I just came across the issue. I'll comment/answer back if I can find any solution.

Answer (score -2):

First take backup of your project then,
You need to remove all your controllers, texts, buttons,styles from that view, and then add them brick by brick

everytime make build of it and check it, by this way you will get your solution.

for me it was css of h3 tag.

that was hiding text in input.